# Using glob pattern in azure file copy task

Tags: azure-devops, glob

I have a long windows directory name. I am doing copy to another folder. Can I use a glob pattern rather then using full path to subfolder "PackageTmp"? Basically **I want to copy all files and subfolder from *PackageTmp* folder to another folder**. Its [Azure Copy file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

```
 Source Directory path : C:\unzip\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp
 Target Directory Path : C:\deploy
 Actual Target directory path : C:\deploy\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp
```

Azure Syntax. s.name is variable.

```
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ s.name }}/unzip/'
          Contents: '**/PackageTmp/**'
          TargetFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ s.name }}/deploy/'
          CleanTargetFolder: true
          OverWrite: true
```

Comment: Do you get any error when you use Copy file task? Copy Files task support File matching patterns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops.

Comment: I do not get any error, C:\deploy\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp is where file copied, I was expecting at C:\deploy

Comment: Is folder `PackageTmp` in `C:\deploy\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package` or `C:\deploy`?

Comment: Updated question, Just wanted to copy "C:\unzip\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp" to "C:\deploy" but it is copying to "C:\deploy\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp"
value of middle directory keep changing "Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package" So is it possible to use like C:\unzip\**PackageTmp\*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the task input like this:

```
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ s.name }}/unzip/Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp'
      Contents: '**'
      TargetFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ s.name }}/deploy/'
```

Comment: Yes, Thats looks like way, But can we avoid giving full path like unzip/Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp'

Comment: I'm afraid we can not avoid the full path, as `SourceFolder` argument doesn't accept file matching patterns, it doesn't recognize something like `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ s.name }}/unzip/*/PackageTmp`.